# try to sort arrays using compareTo() but getting error

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Dog {
 int size;
 String name;

 //Deploying a constructor
 Dog(String name, int size){
     this.name=name;
     this.size=size;
 }

 //Deploying toString() for printing
 public String toString(){
 return name+"/"+size;
 }

 //Deploying compareTo() method and overriding it for int value
 public int compareTo(Object s){
 return (this.size-((Dog)s).size);
 }
}
import java.util.Arrays;
public class CompareTo {
public static void main(String[] args){
     Dog[] obj=new Dog[5];
 obj[0]=new Dog("Alpha",332);
 obj[1]=new Dog("Romeo",32);
 obj[2]=new Dog("Charlie",332);
 obj[3]=new Dog("Tyson",632);
 obj[4]=new Dog("Roger",532);
//Without Sorting taking the output
 for(Object x:obj){
    System.out.println(x);
}
//With Sorting taking the output
     try{Arrays.sort(obj);
     for(Object x: obj){
        System.out.println(x);
     }
    }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Something is wrong in this line"+e);
    }
   }
  }

Output-Alpha/332
Romeo/32
Charlie/332
Osama/632
Laden/532
Something is wrong in this linejava.lang.ClassCastException: Dog cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

Hi,
I was trying to short the Dog object on the basis of size of the dogs. I downcast object x of supermostclass to Dog class but don't know why at runtime java is executing the try and catch block saying that Dog can't be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have specified the `compareTo` method, but you didn't declare the `Dog` class to implement `Comparable<Dog>`.  Also, once you do, you'll need to declare the `s` parameter of `compareTo` to be a `Dog`.

Answer (score 2):

How would you expect `Arrays.sort(obj)` to work if it doesn't know how to compare two `Dog`s to see which one would come first?  `Dog` should implement `Comparable<Dog>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your  Dog  class  must implements to the interface `Comparable`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `implements` keyword, along with the name of the implemented interface (`Comparable` in this case), also, you can grab the opportunity to infer generic argument `<Dog>`:

```
public class Dog implements Comparable<Dog>{
    int size;
    String name;
...
```

Using generics your code has to be changed a bit: instead of `Object`, you need `Dog` as the argument type of `compareTo()`.

Also, you might consider using the `@Override` annotation on `compareTo()` to make things nicer:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Dog s){
...
```

(Notice the Dog type argument here!)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to implement the Comparable interface in Dog class. Your Dog class should like below.

```
  class Dog  implements Comparable<Dog> {

   int size;
   String name;

  // Deploying a constructor
  Dog(String name, int size) {
      this.name = name;
      this.size = size;
  }

  // Deploying toString() for printing
  public String toString() {
       return name + "/" + size;
  }

  // Deploying compareTo() method and overriding it for int value
  public int compareTo(Dog s) {
    return this.size - s.size;
  }
}
```